# Why does the UserChangeForm model does create an object instead of update it in this case?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm using UserChangeForm to update user Form now when I try to send by the request post the function does works but doesn't change the user object but instead, it saves the object like create method does.
so, at this moment how can, I change the form object?

views.py

```
# Edit Your account
@login_required
def edit_profile(request, user_slug=None):
    template_name = 'account/edit_profile.html'
    if request.method == "POST":
        request_user = request.user.userprofile
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(slug=user_slug)
        form = EditForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.slug = user_slug
            form.save()
            return redirect('account:view_profile', form.instance.slug)
        return render(request, template_name, {'form': form})
    else:
        form = EditForm()
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(slug=user_slug)
        return render(request, template_name, {'form': form})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('view-profile/<slug:user_slug>/', views.view_profile, name='view_profile'),
    # /account/edit-profile/
    path('edit-profile/<slug:user_slug>/', views.edit_profile, name='edit_profile'),
]
```

edit_form.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %} Edit Profile {% endblock %}

{% block body %}

    <div class="edit-form">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="my-form">
                <form method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {% for field in form %}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">{{ field.label_tag }}</label>
                        <p>{{ field }}</p>
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Change Password</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    {% include 'base_footer.html' %}

{% endblock %}
```

forms.py

```
# Edit your data except password
class EditForm(UserChangeForm):
    password = None

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')

    def edit(self, fields):
        user = super(EditForm, self).save(commit=False)

        if user.commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to provide an edit function on your ModelForm, and I would suggest to use Class based generic view as it is easy to use and extends. Here is what I would suggest:

Forms.py

```
class UpdateUserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email']
```

#views.py

```
from django.views.generic import View
from .forms import UpdateUserForm
from django.contrib import messages
#import your forms and functions including UpdateUserForm

class UserView(View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = UpdateUserForm(instance=self.request.user)
        context = {'form':form}
        return render(self.request, template, context)

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = UpdateUserForm(self.request.POST or None, instance=self.request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(self.request, 'Info updated')
            return redirect('user-profile')
        context = {'form':form}
        messages.error(self.request, 'Please, check the form for errors')
        return render(self.request, template, context)



#function based view
def update_user(request):
    form = UpdateUserForm(instance=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateUserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render(...)
    return render(request, template, {'form':form}
```

This is how I create my view for user info update and it works like a charm

template file

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %} Edit Profile {% endblock %}

{% block body %}

<div class="edit-form">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="my-form">
            <form method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% for field in form %}

                            <div
                                class="input-group no-border form-control-lg {% if field.errors %} has-danger {% endif %} ">
                                <span class="input-group-prepend">
                                    <div class="input-group-text">
                                        <i class="now-ui-icons users_single-02"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </span>
                                {% render_field field class="form-control" %}
                            </div>

                            {% if field.errors %}
                            {% for error in field.errors %}
                            <div class="text-left text-danger font-weight-bolder">
                                <p>{{ error|escape}}</p>
                            </div>
                            <script>
                            $('.form-control').addClass('form-control-danger')
                            </script>
                            {% endfor %}
                            {% endif %}

                            {% endfor %}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Change Password</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% include 'base_footer.html' %}

{% endblock %}
```

if you use Bootstrap, you can add styles using Javascript

```
{% block page_script %}
<script>
var $list = $("form :input[type='text']");
$list.each(function () {
    $(this).addClass("form-control");
});
var $select = $("form select");
$select.each(function () {
    $(this).addClass("custom-select w-90");
});
var $select = $("form textarea");
$select.each(function () {
    $(this).addClass("form-control");
});
var $list = $("form :input[type='number']");
$list.each(function () {
    $(this).addClass("form-control");
});
```

```
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: thanks for what you say I know really that but I want to use that way by method for a while if you have a solution I'll be glad

Comment: I have added a function based view, check it out.

Comment: I see your code is the same as my code but it has made just by class-based view!

Comment: Thank you @Fahrer but I really don't understand what is the difference between them I see that the two ways are close so, what if I did create by normal method what is the mistake I did before?

Answer (score 0):

> Every `ModelForm` also has a save() method. This method creates and saves a database object from the data bound to the form. A subclass of `ModelForm` can accept an existing model **instance** as the keyword argument instance; **if this is supplied, save() will update that instance. If it’s not supplied, save() will create a new instance of the specified model**

Therefore, you can simply pass **instance** to your `EditForm`

```
# Edit Your account
@login_required
def edit_profile(request, user_slug=None):
    template_name = 'account/edit_profile.html'
    if request.method == "POST":
        request_user = request.user.userprofile
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(slug=user_slug)
        # if instance is supplied, save will update instead of create
        form = EditForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user_profile)
        print(form.errors) # check if any errors
        if form.is_valid():
            # form.instance.slug = user_slug
            form.save()
            return redirect('account:view_profile', form.instance.slug)
        return render(request, template_name, {'form': form})
    else:
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(slug=user_slug)
        # prepopulate the form data with model instance
        form = EditForm(instance=user_profile)
        return render(request, template_name, {'form': form})
```

NOTE: if you also upload images, remember to pass `request.FILES` as well

Comment: at this time returns an empty request and the object does not save

Comment: @abdelhamedabdin slug is already there for instance, so you don't need to set it again. `print(form.errors)` to see if there are same validation errors

Comment: No error appears but instead, I get a number 6 in the print I don't know what is this

Comment: @abdelhamedabdin if no errors, then `form.is_valid()` will be called, it's really strange that you form data is not properly stored

Comment: @abdelhamedabdin pass `request.FILES` as well if you are uploading profile image.

Comment: No, the data is just a text field I get from user model to edit it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216855/discussion-between-abdelhamed-abdin-and-minglyu).